# To create product Flavors in already published application without flavor and only with defaultconfig

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I have one app published on playstore.
in app level gradle i have code like below

```
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.main"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

I want to add one more flavor using prodctFlavor. How should i proceed so that original flavor i.e 'com.abc.main' remain intact.

I have tried changing default config appid to some random eg com.bcd.
And added two flavour in 'main' 'main1'. I also created 1 more directory 'main1' in root directory. But it is not creating main1 as different flavor.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your whole gradle.build file?

Comment: @MikelPascual , I am experimenting in my changes in gradle file , so there is not much to share except above description . If you want i can explain again.

Comment: how are you trying to create main1 build? You need to go to Gradle(in right side of android studio)->root folder name->Tasks->install and then you can choose between the flavours.

Answer (score 0):

Creating product flavors is similar to creating build types: add them to the productFlavors block and configure the settings you want. The product flavors support the same properties as defaultConfig—this is because defaultConfig actually belongs to the ProductFlavor class. This means you can provide the base configuration for all flavors in the defaultConfig block, and each flavor can change any of these default values.

In Your case add This this in your **app** level `build.gradle` under the `android` tag

```
 productFlavors {
    pro {
        applicationId "com.abc.main1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    lite{
        applicationId "com.abc.main2_lite"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
 }
```

Refer [Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors) for more details

Aditional reference: http://blog.brainattica.com/how-to-work-with-flavours-on-android/

Comment: This way will main product i.e com.abc.main remain intact ? 
I have already published app with 'com.abc.main' .

Comment: you can add anothe one  'live' flavor in it and select this while creating signed APK.